# numeric_limits lowest and min member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, standard-library

```
numeric_limits<T>::min();
numeric_limits<T>::lowest();
```

What is the different between the value returned by both functions?

Comment: [For future readers], the table at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits, explains it quite well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Paragraph 18.3.2.4 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> `static constexpr T min() noexcept`;
>
> 1 Minimum finite value.
>
> 2 For floating types with denormalization, returns the minimum positive normalized value.
>
> 3 Meaningful for all specializations
>
> [...]
>
> `static constexpr T lowest() noexcept`;
>
> 6 A finite value x such that there is no other finite value y where y < x.
>
> 7 Meaningful for all specializations in which is_bounded != false.

Footnote 197 then adds the relevant remark:

> `lowest()` is necessary because not all floating-point representations have a smallest (most negative) value that is the
> negative of the largest (most positive) finite value.

Comment: in another word `lowest` return something like the 2s complement for maximum positive integer.

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: for integer types there is no difference between `min()` and `lowest()`.

Answer (score 15):

For floating point types `min` returns the smallest finite number that is `> 0` representable in the type (i.e. the number having the lowest absolute value `!= 0`) while `lowest` returns the smallest finite number that is representable (i.e. the negative number of maximal absolute value that is greater than `-infinity`).

Comment: The smallest number that is representable is negative infinity; `lowest` give the smallest **finite** representable value.